# Why it is doing part assignment?

Tags: assignment

I am writing an algorithm and need to keep updating an association called "verticesAssoc". My algorithm ran perfectly at first. However now I want to use the same algorithm on another association "verticesAssocPart[i, j]", where the index will be given. I changed all "verticesAssoc" into "verticesAssocPart[i, j]", so I think literally there should be no problem, it is just like changing the name of a variable. However the bugs kept coming up saying "xxx in the part assignment is not a symbol". Why it worked before with "verticesAssoc" but now it fails with "verticesAssocPart[i, j]"? There shouldn't be any problem because no matter it's the "verticesAssoc" or "verticesAssocPart[i, j]", they are not passed as parameters into a module since my module is simply doing operations on them.

I checked the stack trace and as you can see at the **If** part I am doing a **MemberQ** check, and then it says I am doing an illegal part assignment. I can't see where the problem is, can someone help me?

My association stores information in the form <|pt_1 -> {{pt_2, "s"}, {pt_3, "d"}}|>, where "pt"s are 5D coordinates and "s/d" is simply a string.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, get used to post copyable code so that we can try it out easily. Nobody wants to retype everything or parse your code in _gedanken Mathematica_.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought it won't help much to put codes here since my algorithm is too long, but the idea is that I have an association, and I am updating it by a module (I am pretty sure I don't pass the association as a parameter into the module). It works perfectly well. Then I want to use that module to update an association with another name. I substitute all old names in the module and then it doesn't work.

Comment: Really, this cannot be answered without looking at the actual code that you use. Please provide a _minimal_ example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, as the error says, `verticesAssocPart[i,j]` is not a symbol. Essentially what happens is that `verticesAssocPart[i,j][…]=…` becomes `<|…|>[…]=…` in a first step, which is clearly meaningless (Unlike in most programming languages, nearly everything in Mathematica is immutable - so `verticesAssocPart[i,j]` is not a reference to some mutable association, but an immutable copy of that association).

What should work in your case is `verticesAssocPart[[i,j,Key[…]]=…`, since now there's nothing to prematurely evaluate, only a single (nested) part assignment. Without seeing your code, more specific help will be impossible.